# If statement evaluation?

Tags: python, if-statement

I currently am having issues with this line of code

```
roomChoice = input("Choose 1-3: ")

if roomChoice == 1:
    print("You went to the bar, and lost $5, your total loot is : " + main.totalLoot)
else:
    print(roomChoice)
```

Whenever I input `1`, it prints out `1` instead of evaluating the first `if` statement.

Comment: yes, as the answer below hints, you are comparing unequal things a string "1" and a number/value 1.  They are not equal and will only lead to the else clause.

Answer (score 0):

Use "1" instead of 1:

```
roomChoice = input("Choose 1-3: ")

if roomChoice == "1":
    print("You went to the bar, and lost $5, your total loot is : " + main.totalLoot)
else:
    print(roomChoice)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to cast the input value to integer before the if statement.
use

```
if int(roomChoice) == 1:
    print("You went to the bar, and lost $5, your total loot is : " + main.totalLoot)
else:
    print(roomChoice)
```